# Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string' C# SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, methods

I have this problem

```
private void ContruirGrelha()
{
    SqlConnection conectar = new SqlConnection(Metodos.BaseDeDados);
    conectar.Open();
}
```

In `Metodos.BaseDeDados` it tells me that I:

> Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

```
public static partial class Metodos
{
    public static void BaseDeDados()
    {
        SqlConnection conectar = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-VJ9V9CM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Agenda;Integrated Security=True");
        conectar.Open();
        ...
    }
}
```

Metodos.BaseDeDados conect the SQL server to my programa, and he had all my data, he has all the contet of my SQL data base, and i want to use his conection and data in my "private void ConstruirGrelha()" to build a datagrid. Sorry for the bad english

Comment: It's probably Metodos.BaseDeDados() <- a method not a property.

Comment: Duplicate contains explanation of the exact error (so at least future visitors searching for similar error get answer), but code in the question does not make much sense (in particular `new SqlConnection(Metodos.BaseDeDados)`), so it is hard to know which way you wanted it fixed.

Comment: Why are you using `Metodos.BaseDeDados` in `new SqlConnection`?

Comment: Metodos.BaseDeDados conect the SQL server to my programa, and he had all my data, he has all the contet of my SQL data base, and i want to use his conection and data in my "private void ConstruirGrelha()" to build a datagrid. Sorry for the bad english